# MongoDB/Mongoose: Delete an object from array or the whole document based on the array size

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have a document with this structure:

```
{
    "Category": ["Car"],
    "Price": [1, 100000],
    "userInfo": [{
        "userId": "60734e234948882f20cb31de",
        "userName": "apple"
    }, {
        "userId": "6060d3cd8231610848942f69",
        "userName": "test"
    }]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to delete an element from my userInfo array by username. And if the userInfo array would become empty delete the whole document.

A little example: I want to delete the `userName="test"` member and my document wil look like:

```
"Category": ["Car"],
"Price": [1, 100000],
"userInfo": [{
        "userId": "60734e234948882f20cb31de",
        "userName": "apple"
    }]
```

Later if I delete the `userName="apple"` my array would become empty so I want to delete the whole document.

Can I achieve this with only one query or I should write one for delete and another one for checking the emptiness of the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to write separate query for delete main document, `.deleteMany({ userInfo: [] })`

Comment: Actually I find the document by ID so I don't need to use deleteMany just deleteOne, but thank you.